# Why is agriculture still in existence in 24th century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek: Picard*, you can see big farm and cool futuristic farming machines on Picard's estate.

But, given, small replicators weren't exotic devices limited only to starships (in the beginning, it was shown in an apartment to produce food), why was agriculture still in existence?

Talking about hobbyists, they could only protect the industry upto a kitchen garden. Those big farming machines meant that agriculture as an industry had somehow survived. How so?

Comment: Those big farming machines can be replicated as needed, no industry required.

Comment: What would grouchy old men who distrust technology and society *do* all day if not agriculture?

Comment: @Valorum Replicators aren't magic. You still need to "design" big farming machines down to their molecular structures (this is invention class thing in which only manufacturing process became easy). Plus, big replicators aren't common. There's a reason damaged starships needed to go to repair yards. Getting big replicators' time shouldn't be easy. Definitely, an industry is required.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation - I hardly think so. Once an item like that is designed, it can then be freely distributed since there ain't no money on Earth. I would imagine that machines like that are patterned by interested nerds in committee.

Comment: @Valorum:   Various dialog in ST:P clearly shows that there is money of some form.

Comment: @Valorum `it can then be freely distributed since there ain't no money on Earth.` ~> You seem to have no idea about cost of time.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation - People on Earth seem to have no end of time on their hands. One of the benefits of not having to worry about money

Comment: @ThePopMachine - I ascribe that to the writers having never seen any Star Trek before they started writing what amounts to an action-film parody of the show

Comment: @Valorum I am talking about industrial replicator time. Replication takes time and there should be big queues for essential item replication. One of the reasons why another Earth wasn't created by hobbyists using replicators.

Comment: Star Trek: Picard, like the rest of "New Trek," doesn't care at all about continuity.

Comment: Isn't Picard's farm a vineyard? Throughout the series of TNG various characters complain of the inferior taste of "synthahol" compared with the real thing, so it would make sense that people would want wine brewed from real grapes!

Answer (score 14):

- Memory Alpha [mentions](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Replicator) that some people simply objected to replicators, either because they felt that they made people complacent or that they couldn't produce the best food. One of these objectors was Picard's brother, who most likely had an interest in the Picard estate shown on-screen or perhaps his own farm.
- Earth in the 24th century is post-scarcity, so people theoretically don't have to work *at all* if they don't want to. Picard explains it in *First Contact* - that "We work to better ourselves". Some people (like Picard in this case) are probably farming because *that's what they like to do*, not because they need to do so to survive.
- It's probably a research area. In the 23rd century, the main conflict behind The Trouble with Tribbles (TOS) is a competition to develop a viable crop for Sherman's Planet in accordance with treaty stipulations (the government that can best do it gets to settle the planet). Having agricultural capabilities is most likely still important in the 24th century for that reason - it's the sign of a healthy society and demonstrates capability and flexibility.
- What happens if replicators fail or are not available? *Voyager* had to conserve power and as a result there was a lot of more traditional food preparation seen. Kes built a hydroponics project in a cargo bay, and Neelix did a lot of manual cooking, which apparently was easier on the ship's systems than replicating every meal.

Comment: I would add that many a Star Trek episode featured a moment when the characters were salivating at someone having scored "real food".  They often made a dinner party occasion of their offering.  One or two characters suggests a foodie-gourment snob.  But it happened frequently enough to suggest that replicated food was only...adequate.  Probably classically made wine with the Picard label was in eager demand.

Comment: @Blaze exactly. It's like that in our own world too. Why do people bother to grill their own burgers in their backyard when they can just get some at McDonald's?

Comment: “Just like mom used to make”.........is not something a replicator can produce. Something made with human attention, passion, and in many cases love, is far different from a computer-driven machine that turns matter into solidified energy in the form of edibles/drinks.

Comment: Sisko cooks by hand. Think his dad referred to replicated food as "Starfleet slop"

Answer (score 2):

Mostly, this is just a plot hole.

[This TrekMovie article](https://trekmovie.com/2017/08/22/ron-moore-star-trek-writers-hated-the-replicator/#:%7E:text=One%20of%20the%20major%20bits,even%20seen%20in%20crew%20quarters.) has most of the information you need, but I'll also give some informational quotes (that basically summarizes it):

> One of the major bits of technology introduced in Star Trek: The Next Generation – and seen throughout the 24th century Trek shows – was replicators. These handy devices could make almost anything and they were so ubiquitous, they were even seen in crew quarters. **While an interesting bit of sci-fi tech, Star Trek: TNG and DS9 writer/producer Ron Moore feels they were bad for the show.**

(Emphasis Mine)

Ron Moore said:

> Replicators are the worst thing ever. Destroys storytelling all the time. They mean there’s no value to anything. Nothing has value in the universe if you can just replicate everything, so all that goes away. Nothing is unique; if you break something, you can just make another one. If something breaks on the ship, it’s “Oh, no big deal, Geordi [LaForge] can just go down to engineering and make another doozywhatsit.” Or they go to a planet and that planet needed something: “Oh, hey, let’s make them what they need!” [The writers room] just hated it and tried to forget about it as much as possible.

In other words, replicators really sucked the juice, or the seasoning, or...the realness out of it.

And, this is just speculation, but I think I might be capable of providing and in-universe answer:

People just really liked fresh food.

Since there seems to be a slight difference between real and replicated food, people might have really enjoyed "real" food. This real food probably wouldn't have been meat, for people wouldn't have chained animals in the humane, peaceful 24th century. I guess that in a way, it's like the difference between organic and inorganic food. Organic food is considered cleaner, more healthy and uncontaminated, where as inorganic food is cheaper and often dirtier.

Jean-Luc Picard has a chateau, but anyone who wanted wine could just replicate it any day, any hour, any minute. But he raises real grapes and makes real wine.

In *Star Trek: Voyager,  "Non Sequitir,"* Harry Kim goes to a cafe. Again, the coffee should be replicable, but it's sold in a coffee shop.

So, I think that real food (fruit and vegetables) is still grown and raised, because people enjoy it, and it is a very unique part of human life.

Comment: Ron Moore at least got his own way in Battlestar Galactica, where everything was scarce except paper with the corners cut off!

Answer (score 1):

It *could* be that various script writers introduced inconsistencies into the setting over the decades. But that's breaking the fourth wall, so consider:

- We know that in 2375 Joseph Sisko operated a restaurant. This restaurant was large enough to keep least three people more-or-less busy.
- While operating the restaurant might have been a kind-of-hobby for Joseph, given the state of Earth economy, it clearly operates on a scale that would require significant food deliveries beyond the capacity of *any one* kitchen garden.
- Just as Joseph takes pride in setting a table, it seems reasonable that others would provide wholesome, authentic shrimps, or wine, or grain.

Comment: One would assume that those that supply their home produced food to his restaurant would also get preferential booking to eat there.

Comment: @Valorum, that would turn it into a kind of barter economy, or a SCA fair ...

Comment: @o.m. yes, that's what I seem to be inferring from the context of 24th century Earth. Nobody has to starve on the streets if they don't want to. If you want to live a life of luxury with a substantial social network (e.g. Malibu mansion, country club membership with a reserved seat at the racetrack, etc.), you have to work for that, which might include producing something valued by the social network you want to associate with.